# I need to create a dynamic query using StreamInsight 2.1 and reactive extensions

Tags: linq, dynamic, streaminsight

I am looking for information about how to create dynamic queries using the newer StreamInsight 2.1 reactive extensions model. Specifically, I would like to use the CreatQuery() method or something similar (within IQueryable) with IQStreamable. Within the workflow I am creating, this new query would be inserted into StreamInsight as a standing query. I have done quite a bit of research but have not found a solution. Also, most of the documentation appears to reference what is now a "legacy" adapter model. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "Dynamic Query"? Something similar to Dynamic Query Composition, where you could use the output of one query as a stream input into another query? If that's the case, you can use Subjects for this. Subjects allow you to have multiple publishers/subscribers for a stream and also provide the ability to attach/detach publishers and subscribers at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember StreamInsights does not support that concept, the only way to archive that would be to use dynamic compilation to publish to StreamInsights query instance compiled based on dynamically generated code. That is quite possible.